# Issue with C++ inheritance and 'const' interraction

Tags: c++, inheritance, constants

I have tree different classes, which we'll call Locomotion, Walk and TimeInfo.

```
class TimeInfo {
  int timeAtEnd() const {return mTimeAtEnd;}
}

class Locomotion {
  // Stuff
  virtual float getDistanceTravelled() const = 0;  
  virtual int getTimeAtEnd() const = 0;  
}

class Walk : public Locomotion, public TimeInfo {
  // Stuff
  float Walk::getDistanceTravelled() const {return mDistanceTravelled;}  // Works
  int Walk::getTimeAtEnd() const {return TimeInfo::timeAtEnd();}   // DO NOT WORK
}
```

My issue is that at another part of my program I have access to a pointer to a Locomotion object, which may in reality be to a Walk object, or to some other class that extends both Locomotion and TimeInfo. From this Locomotion pointer I need to be able to get the *timeAtEnd* value. I am having problems doing this as I am not allowed to have Locomotion itself extend TimeInfo and when I try to compile with the code as above I get the following error:

```
error: non-member function 'int TimeInfo::timeAtEnd()' cannot have cv-qualifier
```

As far as I understand the issue is that I do not actually have a TimeInfo Object available inside *Walk::getTimeAtEnd()* but I have no idea how to solve this...

Comment: Are you sure you have the scoping `Walk::` in the class itself? That doesn't make sense. Is this [mcve] what you really have? Does it replicate the error you get and nothing more? Is the single error line you show all that the compiler is telling you?

Comment: You do not get that error message when you try to compile that code.

Comment: Also, a `Walk` isn't a `TimeInfo`, maybe pick composition instead.

Comment: @Mansoor It's legal to call a non-static member function using the `Class::` qualification, as long as the context is another member function so that the implicit `this->` is valid and has an appropriate type.

Comment: I'm afraid this probably isn't the minimal reproducible example. The original program contains several million lines of code, and the company I work on sadly do not enforce the writing of comments (so there are none) and all who originally wrote the program have left the company.

Comment: Can you extend your code by adding the access modifiers (public, protected, private) that you use in your actual code?

Comment: @AnjuMaaka - no it is not a [mcve].    Problem is, that forces people to guess what is actually causing your problem, and reduces the chances of anyone being able to succeed in helping you.    So you need to invest effort to ask a better question.

Comment: After I fixed all the syntactical errors and omissions, worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the timeAtEnd() to constant, then it will work.

```
class TimeInfo {
    int mTimeAtEnd;
protected:
  int timeAtEnd() const {return mTimeAtEnd;}
};
```

Comment: Sorry, missed the 'const' in int timeAtEnd() but is is 'const' there, and there is a mTimeAtEnd variable in the header file

Comment: As per your code, timeAtEnd() returning value from mTimeAtEnd. So I assume it would be member variable in class TimeInfo. The function can return a global variable, also. const keyword make the function a constant function, then only you can call it from another constant function.